# multilingual static block does not working

Tags: magento, content-management-system, multilingual, magento-1.8

I created a multilingual static block on Magneto admin-> cms -> static block and call into under `catalog -> manage catagories -> category name -> display setting` and set to CMS Block from select dropdown.

My static block identifier name is `home_cat` for both language.

It works on English language but not working in my Arabic language website. Thanks

Comment: have you assign the static block to all stores?

Comment: yes I assigned store view "English" to english website and store view "Arabic" to arabic website.

Comment: 'm not asking  that. The static block is assigned to both store views or not?

Comment: yes I assign for both

Comment: have you create two static block or one ?

Comment: I created two blocks with same identifier.

Comment: Are the static blocks enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the static block to category with different `store view`.

[image]